# Using Ado.net and SqlCeEngine together in SQL Compact edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have an application for Windows CE 5 that uses Ado.net to backup/Restore the database I do simple copy.

Before restoring a database from a backup I use `SqlCeEngine` to verify that the database is OK and fix it if not. This works fine but when I restore large database after few times I get verify method returns false and the repair functions throw an exception

> Could not load sqlcecompact30.dll. Operation has been aborted.

This happens now for every database file I want to restore until I exit the application.

Could not find the reason if I remove the test and repair everything is working OK and the database is OK but I want to check if the database is corrupted before restoring it.

I use the following CAB files to install the SQL on the PDA (iPAQ 310).

- sqlce30.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB
- sqlce30.repl.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB
- Visual Studio 2005
- Microsoft SQL server 2005 compact
- Microsoft ssql Client 2.0

This is the code for verify and repair:

```
private static SqlCeEngine CreateEngine(string DBFileName)
        {
            return new SqlCeEngine("Data Source = '" + DBFileName + "'");
        }

        static public bool CheckDB(string DBFileName)
        {
            SqlCeEngine engine = null;
            try
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DBFileName);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    engine = CreateEngine(DBFileName);
                    return engine.Verify();                    
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (engine != null)
                {
                    engine.Dispose();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        static public bool RepairDB(string DBFileName)
        {
            SqlCeEngine engine = null;
            try
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DBFileName);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    engine = CreateEngine(DBFileName);
                    engine.Repair(null, RepairOption.RecoverCorruptedRows);
                    return engine.Verify();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Ness300Logger.Logger.Log("Repair failed: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (engine != null)
                {
                    engine.Dispose();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```